# Migration to IE9

Tags: browser, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-9

I had an application running on IE7, then, after the release of IE8, I could migrate my application to view with IE8.

Now IE 9 is already happened. What are the tips and tricks to migrate my application to IE9 ? I did a workaround, but I am not satisfied with it. I use the following to set the `Document mode` to IE 7.

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />`

What are the best ways to handle with IE 9 ?

The gap between elements are widened in IE9 ? How can I modify my site to work well in IE7, IE8 and IE9 ?

**The application looks fine in IE7 and IE8. Did Microsoft forget about backward compatibility ?**

Answer (score 0):

I gather that your application does not render properly in IE9? You seem to be looking for a "quick fix" to make your application keep rendering the same as it did in IE7 without having to make any significant changes. Such a trick/hack may exist (I don't know), but I'd recommend against it. Eventually you're going to have to update your web app to work with modern browsers -- why not do it now? IE9 is by far the most standards-compliant version of IE, and you would benefit in the long run by making your web app render correctly in IE9 without any "pretend to be IE7" tricks.